# Apache Spark vs Apache Spark 2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

What are the improvements Apache Spark2 brings compared to Apache Spark?

1. From architecture perspective
2. From application point of view
3. or more

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Apache Spark 2.0.0 APIs have stayed largely similar to 1.X, Spark
>   2.0.0 does have API breaking changes

**Apache Spark 2.0.0** is the first release on the 2.x line. The major updates are *API usability, SQL 2003 support, performance improvements, structured streaming, R UDF support, as well as operational improvements*.

> New in spark 2:

- The biggest change that I can see is that DataSet and DataFrame APIs will be merged.
- The latest and greatest from Spark will be a whole lot efficient as compared to predecessors. Spark 2.0 is going to focus on a combination of Parquet and caching to achieve even better throughput.
- Structured streaming is another big thing!
- It will be the first version that will focus on ETL. Successive versions will add more operators and libraries for ETL

You can go through the [Spark release 2.0.0](http://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html) where updates in following points are explained:

- API Stability
- Core and Spark SQL
- MLlib
- SparkR
- Streaming
- Dependency, Packaging, and Operations
- Removals, Behavior Changes and Deprecations
- Known Issues

Answer (score 5):

There is not much difference with respect to architecture as the nutshell is still DAG and RDD , which is the most important part of it !

Though Spark 2.0 is much more optimized and has DataSet Api which gives much more powerful to the hands of developers. 
So I would say the architecture is same it is just the Spark 2.0 provides much optimized and has a rich set of Api !

These are the main things that are provided by Apache Spark 2.0:

- The biggest change that I can see is that DataSet and DataFrame APIs
  will be merged.
- The latest and greatest from Spark will be a whole
  lot efficient as compared to predecessors. Spark 2.0 is going to
  focus on a combination of Parquet and caching to achieve even better
  throughput.
- Structured streaming is another big thing!
- It will be the
  first version that will focus on ETL. Successive versions will add more operators and libraries for ETL

For more information please take a lok here : https://www.quora.com/What-are-special-features-and-advantages-of-Apache-Spark-2-0-over-earlier-versions